# Can we conclude that these functions are constant?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have smooth functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\;\alpha,\beta:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ which is a cartesian product of nonempty intervals. These functions have the property that for all $\langle x, y, z\rangle \in S$,

$$g(z) = \alpha(x,y) f(z) + \beta(x,y).$$

Edited question:

[Under what conditions] can I conclude that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant functions when restricted to $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ in $S$? After all, the left hand side depends only on $z$.

Comment: What you have doesn't say that all triplets are in $S.$  There is some set of triplets such that $g(z) = \alpha(x,y) f(z) + \beta(x,y).$

Comment: What if $\alpha(x,y) = xy = -\beta(x,y)$ and $f(z) =1$. Certainly they are not constant but the above still holds.

Comment: With the edit, this seems like a very broad question. I don't think there's any good answer to this one.

Answer (score 0):

If $f = 0$, $\alpha$ can be not constant.